# Enabling Anti-Aliasing in NVIDIA Control Panel causes line distortion in orthographic projection

Tags: opengl, drawing, antialiasing, nvidia, orthographic

On this OpenGL application that I'm developing on Windows 7 with Visual Studio, I tried to enable Anti-Aliasing on the NVIDIA Control Panel (only for the application .exe).

Enabling that causes a little bit of distortion in lines/quads drawn in orthographic projection.

Anti-aliasing is turned off on the left and turned on on the right:

[image: anti-aliasing issue]

How can this be fixed keeping anti-aliasing on?

In case it's relevant, here's how the orthographic projection is setup and how black border is drawn:

```
void drawHeadsUpDisplay(void) {
    static int winWidth, winHeight;

    winWidth = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    winHeight = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    glPushAttrib(GL_ENABLE_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0f, winWidth, winHeight, 0.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex2f(winWidth - 41, 48);
        glVertex2f(winWidth - 41, winHeight - 48);
        glVertex2f(winWidth - 18, winHeight - 48);
        glVertex2f(winWidth - 18, 48);
    glEnd();

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glPopAttrib();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have there 48 and 49 in the y direction. Without antialiasing enabled the integer roundoff due to the projection hides the difference, but with antialiasing enabled you see the slope. Just change to

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(winWidth - 41, 49);
    glVertex2f(winWidth - 41, winHeight - 49);
    glVertex2f(winWidth - 18, winHeight - 49);
    glVertex2f(winWidth - 18, 49);
glEnd();
```

(or 48 everywhere)

Comment: You're right, but that only fixes the slope problem. The lines are still anti-aliased and I don't want that. Well, I do, depending on the situation. In this one, I'm drawing a vertical line where x is constant, why is the line blurred? That's what I want to avoid but keep AA on.

Comment: @Nazgulled:  Most likely the line location itself isn't on an exact pixel location.  With AA off, it gets drawn on the nearest pixel, and with AA on, it gives a little bit of color to the pixels on either side.  This effect would be less noticeable if you used greater line width, if that's an option.

Comment: @Drew Hall, @Nazgulled: It's not that hard to map line positions to exactly window pixels. It's practically the same problem as pixelexact selection of a textures subimage. But a comment won't suffice to explain. I think I'll make this a longer answer, after work.

Comment: @Drew Hall: How come it's not on an exact pixel location? I'm using integers and specifying exact locations, that's what I don't understand. @datenwolf: I would appreciate it.

Comment: Because OpenGL doesn't address pixels. I guess you're using some glViewport(0,0,width,height); glOrtho(0,width,0,height,-1,1); setup for projection. Take a piece of grid ruled paper. The viewport selects the grid cells, but the Ortho projection doesn't hit the grid cell's centers but the grid lines! This is fine if you want to pixel perfect map a texture, because there you got the same problem in reverse and both effects cancel out. But in your case they don't. Instead glOrtho(0.5/width, width-1 + 0.5/width, 0.5/height, height-1 + 0.5/height); should do the trick.

Comment: I tried to adapt that to my code but it's not working. I've added a more complete example to the question. Please take a look, I'm using `gluOrtho2D` and slightly different, since I want the top-left corner to be origin in the ortho view.

Comment: I was actually able to solve the problem with this: `gluOrtho2D(-0.5f, winWidth - 1.0f + 0.5f, winHeight - 1.0f + 0.5f, -0.5f);` but not entirely. It helped a lot but I had to manually sum (or subtract) `0.5f` here and there (I also have a couple of other drawings on the screen). That's what I'm failing to understand. After that change to the orthographic view, why some lines work with exact numbers while others need a 0.5f difference?

Comment: The way I see it, shifting the orthographic projection by 0.5f should be enough to make it work without changing anything else, but I'm probably missing something here. Here's the whole code so you can compare, maybe it can be simplified. Original: http://pastebin.com/wJPYgDBi; Fixed: http://pastebin.com/nET9A1T6; Difference View: http://pastebin.com/diff.php?i=nET9A1T6

Answer (score 1):

Using lines in general isn't the best idea, (You should use textured triangles/rects instead.) but your problem is probably caused by lines falling in-between fragment 'centers' as defined by the standard. You can probably alleviate (if not completely fix) the problem by shifting the coordinates by 0.5, assuming you're using a 1:1 orthographic projection.

Comment: But why are they falling? I'm passing in integers, not floats or anything of that type... Using textures for something like this seems overkill.

Comment: Because pixel centers in OpenGL are at (x+0.5, y+0.5), not (x,y).

Comment: I don't think I'm using a 1:1 orthographic projection, but I'm not sure. I've added a more complete example to my original question. Please take a look.